# Nuxt Content page transition rebuilds the page too quickly

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-content

I've noticed that when navigating from one page to another that fetches Nuxt Content data causes the old page to rebuild with data from the new page. Let me show you what I mean:
https://streamable.com/akj5ei

Or check it out here:
https://rensvis.com/work/be-resilient.

Her's the code:

```
<script setup>
const { path } = useRoute();
const { data } = await useAsyncData('home', () => queryContent('/').where({ _path: path }).findOne());
const articleData = data;
</script>

<template>
  <div>

    <ThePageHeader :title="articleData?.title + '.'"></ThePageHeader>
    <PageWrapper>
      <article class="">
        <ContentDoc />
      </article>

      <!-- related articles -->
      <Container class="max-w-md text-center">
        <h2 class="mb-10">Related work</h2>
      </Container>
      <ContentQuery path="/work" :where="{
        _path: { $ne: articleData['_path'] }
      }" :limit="2" v-slot="{ data }">
        <ContentRenderer :value="data">
          <Container class=" md:flex">

            <WorkItemCard class="block mb-10 sm:basis-1/2 md:mr-3 md:mb-0" :title="data[0].title" :image="data[0].image"
              :route="data[0]._path"></WorkItemCard>

            <WorkItemCard class="block sm:basis-1/2 md:ml-3 md:mt-20" :title="data[1].title" :image="data[1].image"
              :route="data[1]._path"></WorkItemCard>

          </Container>
        </ContentRenderer>
      </ContentQuery>
      <VerticalSpacer></VerticalSpacer>

    </PageWrapper>
  </div>
</template>
```

I'm fetching the data with `queryContent` inside `<script setup>` and am using it in my template. When clicking on a related article the route changes and new data is fetched on the old page, while it is still transitioning to the new page. Since I'm using a .2 second page transition this is very noticeable.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found sort of a workaround by adding a `routePath data variable that is set once.

```
<script>
export default {
  async setup() {
    const route = useRoute();
    const { path } = route;
    const { data } = await useAsyncData('home', () => queryContent('/').where({ _path: path }).findOne());
    const articleData = data;
    return { articleData };
  },
  data() {
    return {
      /**
       * store the current route path to exclude it from the related articles (and not update on route change
       * to avoid rebuild)
       */
      routePath: this.$route.path,
    };
  }
};
</script>

<template>
  <div>

    <ThePageHeader :title="articleData?.title + '.'"></ThePageHeader>
    <PageWrapper>
      <article class="">
        <ContentDoc />
      </article>

      <!-- related articles -->
      <Container class="max-w-md text-center">
        <h2 class="mb-10">Related work</h2>
      </Container>
      <!-- TODO: add date sorting -->
      <ContentQuery path="/work" :where="{
        _path: { $ne: routePath }
      }" :limit="2" v-slot="{ data }">
        <ContentRenderer :value="data">
          <Container class=" md:flex">

            <WorkItemCard class="block mb-10 sm:basis-1/2 md:mr-3 md:mb-0" :title="data[0].title" :image="data[0].image"
              :route="data[0]._path"></WorkItemCard>

            <WorkItemCard class="block sm:basis-1/2 md:ml-3 md:mt-20" :title="data[1].title" :image="data[1].image"
              :route="data[1]._path"></WorkItemCard>

          </Container>
        </ContentRenderer>
      </ContentQuery>

      <VerticalSpacer></VerticalSpacer>

    </PageWrapper>
  </div>
</template>
```